# Create full package path instead of one-by-one in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

**Background**

Say you have a Java project, and you have a somewhat deep package structure. And one of the classes, under the `src/java` folder is

```
com.example.projectname.more.packages.Class
```

Now, I want to create a test for this class, so I have to create, under `src/test`, the class

```
com.example.projectname.more.packages.ClassTest
```

But I have to create the packages one by one, which can get tedious.

**Question**

Is there a way, either in IntelliJ, or by some other tool, to say "create the class with this package path, and auto-create whatever is missing along that path"?

For instance, it could be that I already have the `com.example` package in my `test` root, in which case it would detect this, and create the rest of the path.

Comment: When you have your class open in the editor and in focus, press Ctrl-shift+T, and you will be prompted to open och create a test class, in the right package under test.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer - Beautiful, thanks! I had rebound Ctrl+Shift+T, but I found the relevant mapping. For anyone who might have done the same, it's the bind for `Main Menu | Navigate | Go to test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IntellIJ, when you create a class, its packages will automatically be created.

Just right click the `src/java` directory, and go "New -> Java Class". Enter the package-qualified name of the new class, and all the missing packages will be created:

[image]

For example, assuming I don't have the folders a, b, c, d, e, this will create all of them, in addition to the file Foo.java.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I was trying to do the same but with a deep package, and it wouldn't let me because it tried to interpret the periods as part of the one package name. Good to know the option still exists for creating a deep Class.